# How disable one core from dual core machine

Tags: multi-core

I have a Toshiba Satellite L300 dual core laptop. Due to some problem I need to disable one core. How to do this in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 1):

To do it dynamically, try (as root):

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

(or cpu0 to disable the first core)

To disable one core during boot use maxcpus=1 kernel parameter.

Alternatively, poke around your BIOS, maybe an option in there.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the configuration file

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append this as below example maxcpus=n (n number of CPU) want to enable

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" maxcpus=1"
```

After saving the file run the below command

```
sudo update-grub2
```

When you reboot, linux will run on 1 cores